# Why do I need to use these curly braces on this React Method

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am adding this method to a React Component:

```js
    removeContact = (contact) => {
     this.setState((currentState) => ({
      contacts: currentState.contacts.filter((c) => {
        return c.id !== contact.id
      })
    }))
```

The method modify the state of the Component each time an user press an element's delete button, then re-render the page showing only the not deleted elements. **The method is actually working fine, but I don't understand why do I need the second curly braces** containing the brackets in the arrow function in the second line.

Let me mark what curly braces I am talking about

```js
=> ({
//contacts: currentState...
}))
```

I know an arrow funtion can use either with braces or brackets depending on the content. **But what is the function of curly braces containing brackets?**

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## "(" makes the function auto return & "{" is an opening object bracket

Using "(" makes the function auto return. Its the same as doing

```
=> {
 return {} //contacts: currentState...
})
```

The `{` inside is just a regular object bracket.

So your `() => ({})` is function that automatically returns an object

Comment: Thank for your help Joe!

Answer (score 1):

So basically this means you're returning an object without writing `return`

```
removeContact = (contact) => {
     this.setState((currentState) => ({
      contacts: currentState.contacts.filter((c) => {
        return c.id !== contact.id
      })
}))
```

This is same with this:

```
removeContact = (contact) => {
     this.setState((currentState) => {
      console.log("This is a function and I'm in the scope of function now")
      return {
          contacts: currentState.contacts.filter((c) => {
          return c.id !== contact.id
        }
     }
}))
```